# How to edit pixels in a wndproc window c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, pixel

I have a window in c++ made with the wndproc function. How would I edit the pixels of this screen in the

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        HDC hdc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );
        // ?????
        EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );
    }
```

Comment: You are in dire need of a good read: [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows®-Fifth-Developer-Reference/dp/157231995X/).

Answer (score 2):

When you get the WM_PAINT message the pixels are frequently gone, and/or calling BeginPaint causes the pixels to be erased. So your painting code needs to paint the whole window. If you are merely changing a few pixels you can use an in-memory bitmap, change a few pixels within it (SetPixel is one way), then BitBlt it to the screen to repaint the whole window.

Comment: I tried SetPixel(hdc,10,10,RGB(255,0,0)); but it says undefined reference to _imp_SetPixel

Comment: You need to link to gdi32.a/gdi32.lib

Comment: Calling `SetPixel` to change the color of a pixel in an in-memory bitmap is awkward. Since the bitmap is already in memory, why not simply change the pixel in memory?